# Is it possible to run Nvidia GeForce GTX 970 G1 gaming on ASRock 870 extreme3 r2.0?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, computer-building

I want to build my first gaming PC and I just want to be sure if the following composition is good.
Do you also think that I need a better power supply ?

- CPU--> amd phenom II x4 965 black edition
- GPU--> nvidia geforce gtx 970 gaming g1
- MB--> asrock 870 extreme3 r2.0
- RAM --> 1 x Corsair Vengeance  8GB DDR3 1600 MHz
- Power --> thermaltake berlin 630w
- CPU cooler --> scythe mugen 4

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your combination will work, but there are several aspects you may want to consider:

- Your CPU is relatively old and AMD is not in the advantage at the moment. Maybe an i5 or a Xeon E1231V3 with a fitting motherboard is a better choice
- Your graphics card is a lot faster than your CPU. The CPU will be the limiting factor here.
- Only one RAM stick takes the Dual Channel option from you. The system can read/write on both sticks simaltenously if you have two. Please consider 2x4 or 2x8 GB depending on your needs and budget.

Your PSU should be quite fine. The GTX 970 does not take that much power.

How high is your budget and what do you want to do with your machine? Which games do you play? What else do you use it for?

Comment: you are right all components except from the graphics card are older.
For the moment I just want to go with this and I want to improve my PC in time.
I am going to use it mostly for gaming.

Comment: well, I think it's going to work, so you can go fot the GTX 970. Personally I am no fan of the card because of the 3.5+0.5GB incident. Maybe a GTX 960 is an option, it won't be considerably slower with the other hardware, I guess.